# Gdiplus::Image Object and boost::shared_ptr

Tags: visual-c++, boost, mfc, gdi+, shared-ptr

I have a simple Image cache class in my MFC application, to keep track of images loaded from the file system:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Image> ImagePtr;
typedef std::map<std::string, ImagePtr> ImageMap;
```

Whenever an image is requested by file name, a look up is done, or if it is already loaded, the appropriate ImagePtr is returned.

The problem occurs when I exit my application, and the shared pointer gets destructed.  I get an access violation here, in **checked_delete.hpp**:

```
// verify that types are complete for increased safety

template<class T> inline void checked_delete(T * x)
{
    // intentionally complex - simplification causes regressions
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
    (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
    delete x; // <-------- violation here!!
}
```

Is GDI+ managing these objects for me?  If so, what do I need to do to my shared_ptr so that it doesn't call delete?  Or is something else awry?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be a symptom of calling `GdiplusShutdown` before the pointers are destroyed.

Comment: Hm, I'm not actually calling this explicitly.  But you raise an interesting point, because I rely on smart pointers, and the Image Cache will be destructed on the destructor of the CWinApp-derived class I have.  Time to go try something :)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank-you for pointing me in the right direction.  I called `clear()` on my caches in `ExitInstance` rather than letting them destruct, and voila, no access violation.